# how to include typescript module declarations

Tags: typescript

I have the following declarations:

```
declare var __DEV__: boolean;
declare var BROWSER: boolean;
```

If I have these in an `index.d.ts` file then how do I bring this into a project?

If I do this:

```
import '../../../../types/index.d.ts';
```

I get this error:

> TypeScript declaration files should never be required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways, `/// <reference path="..." />` or through `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "files": [
    "..."
   ]
}
```